# Search row for invalid characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have some rows that may contain special characters or accented letters. I need to detect these rows.
I have this as my current comparison

```
@Str like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9.,& ]%'
```

This works fine for special characters but not for accented letters. I have tried changing collation.

Comment: You mean `[a-zA-Z]` matches accented letters? Weird...

Comment: why not try @str not like '%[a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'  this will give everything that isn't a normal letter or number

Comment: I tried that and didn't work, ended up writing all the letters one by one. it's not pretty but it works.

Comment: I think its the space that I had in my comment that made it not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space after the 9 and add collation. Also I believe that the column `datatype` needs to be `Nvarchar`.

```
@str not like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```